# Word for sharing or to encourage sharing

Tags: word-choice, american-english

Is there any other word for sharing? or to encourage sharing?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I need to write something to encourage sharing information. (Let's share our experiences - something like this). I want to use some different words than usual ones. Please help.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @Louel I have edited the question. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first alternative that comes to mind is "exchange" as in an information exchange or two people exchanging information.

You might also consider approaching from the "teacher/student" angle and use words like "explain," "enlighten," or "educate." Something like "Timmy, please explain what you did last weekend." or "Timmy, enlighten us as to your weekend."

Comment: Thank you. It perfectly fits. I used it here. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65414/gifting-ideas

Comment: Let's exchange IDEAS. ("Exchange" is a transitive verb and needs an object.)

Comment: But, honestly, "share" is much more elegant and and more appropriate for this register.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider **[pool](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/pool)**

> (US) to contribute to a pool, or common fund; make a common interest or form a pool (of)

Comment: Not sure it suits for my case, thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could say: Why don't we open up to each other?

http://www.healthyplace.com/relationships/healthy-relationships/how-to-open-up-and-reveal-yourself-to-others/

Comment: Thanks, but exchange is what suited for my situation. :)

Comment: Did you mean _open_ ***up***? The answer sounds unnatural as written.

Comment: It was a typo. Already edited it.